# Javascript: What is the benefit of using function context vs passing as parameter

Tags: javascript, function, optimization, functional-programming

Other than tricking existing functions that already implement `this` as something, why would you want to write a javascript function so that you need to alter its context (via `.call` or `.apply`) rather than explicitly passing the "context" as another parameter?  Is there a performance benefit?

Example:

```
function tryIncrement(inc, context) {
    context = context || this; // just so we can reuse same fn for the example

    if( typeof context.val!= typeof 1|| typeof inc != typeof 1 ) return false;
    context.val += inc;
    return true;
}

var a = {name: 'A', val: 5}, b = {name: 'B', val: 20};

// reassign internal context
for(var i = 0, n = [1,3,"not a num",5]; i < n.length; i++) {
    if( tryIncrement.call(a, n[i]) ) console.log('incremented', i, n[i], a);
    else console.log('failed to increment', i, n[i], a);
}

// provide explicit context;
// could just as easily declared function so context was first param
// so it looked the same as previous implementation
for(var i = 0, n = [1,3,"not a num",5]; i < n.length; i++) {
    if( tryIncrement(n[i], b) ) console.log('incremented', i, n[i], b);
    else console.log('failed to increment', i, n[i], b);
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To address my main purpose -- *is there a performance benefit using `this` over a function parameter?* -- the answer seems to be **no**:

http://jsperf.com/function-context-vs-parameter

Although [there seems to be a slight benefit](http://jsperf.com/parameter-lookup-vs-instance-variables) (may not be significant, however) around using parameter values instead of instance (`this`) variables within objects.

(Please test for yourself and comment if it's different)

Regarding the purpose being addressed by the other answers: there are some [neat use cases as pointed out by @Aadit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15322626/1037948), maintainability is debatably a personal preference, but [like @ben336 said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15318911/1037948) if you're working with Objects (and thus OOP) then `this` can be more useful.

The [ECMAScript 5th-edition native function `bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) may be an interesting bridge between the two worlds, or at least a time-sucking tangent to explore.

The [instance vs parameter values test](http://jsperf.com/parameter-lookup-vs-instance-variables) referenced above may also be a good example of my point -- if you're building a static library of functionality, you can "hijack" `obj.callback2` by scoping to a different `this`, or just call `obj.callback` directly on your alternate context.

Comment: Your main purpose to asking this question is about performance? That's kind of silly. Did you have *any* reason to believe this was a bottleneck in real code? If not, then there a million other things more important than this.

Comment: Telling me my question is silly is kind of silly, especially because at least 2 other people seem to think it was a decent question, and you took the time to read to the bottom just to comment.  I asked because I wanted to make sure there wasn't something obscure (or obvious) that I was missing, like _"but if you use it in **<this>** case then your performance x1000"_.

Answer (score 1):

> As far as I can tell the use of `this` isn't really any different than
>   another parameter, it just has a more complicated way of being
>   modified.

I think the easiest way to answer your question is to imagine if the creator of the base Javascript language had followed your conventions.

#### A world without `this`

A world without `this` is a scary noisy place with lots of excessive duplication:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4];
arr.reverse(arr); //4321
```

More opportunities for misleading or verbose syntax

```
var str = "stringtobesplit";
"abiglongstringnotbeingsplit".split(str,":");
String.prototype.split(str,":");
```

And its not at all rid of apply at least:

```
Math.max.apply(arr);  //didn't add the initial `this` since it doesn't exist
```

Effectively there would be a choice between creating only global functions, or creating functions on prototypes or objects that made assumptions about the types of the arguments it was receiving but didn't enforce those assumptions.  For instance imagine the toString method in our fantasy world.

You could either create a global toString method which would take in an object of every type ever, and try to make them all work, or you could have a function on the prototypes of each type as it works currently, with no enforcement that it would be called on that type.  Someone could call

```
Array.prototype.toString(str)
```

And we would need to handle it gracefully (for what its worth doing this with apply seems to revert to the Object.prototype.toString and returns `[Object String]`).  So we would need to identify the correct prototype method to call in those cases, which means my guess is that the convention would be to call

```
str.toString(str)
```

or something along those lines.

#### So whats the point?

`this` is built to handle the common case for javascript methods on the prototype chain.  It gives us a shorthand to allow an object to act on itself without duplicating the call to it or having to know exactly what its prototype is.  Without it, we would either have to have no functions on objects, or would have to explicitly call the function on itself every time, introducing extra syntax and potential errors.

`call` and `apply` are the exception cases, and apply at least would have uses even if `this` went away.  Its never a good idea to write your apis to the exception cases.  If you're creating object oriented code, you should use `this` as an easy way to refer to the object that is the context for the call.  If you write this well, then call and apply should be used rarely and in special situations.

#### TL;DR - `this` was designed as part of Javascript for a reason, use it when you're creating methods on objects for more clear and understandable syntax.

Comment: I meant when *we write* a function, why would we write it to depend on the inherent context vs. an explicit context.  As far as I can tell the use of `this` isn't really any different than another parameter, it just has a more complicated way of being modified.

Comment: Ok sorry, I rewrote a fuller explanation.

Comment: I see your point about OOP, but if I wrote JS I could just as easily say `String.reverse(str)` as `str.reverse()` like you do in other languages -- heck, you already use `Math.max(1,2,3)` instead of `1.max(2,3)`.  Maybe it's the difference between functional programming and OOP.

Comment: @drzaus - No offense but `1.max(2, 3)` looks retarded - not to mention that it throws a `SyntaxError`. You'll need to use `(1).max(2, 3)` or `1..max(2, 3)` instead. It's all a matter of preference however. If you want a `Number.prototype.max` method then you may implement it yourself. Personally I feel `max` belongs to the `Math` namespace and not to `Number`. It's important to note that `Math` is a namespace and not a constructor. Thus it makes perfect sense to use `Math.max` - you don't want to pollute the global scope. The `Math` namespace was directly taken from Java - the `java.lang.Math`

Comment: @AaditMShah -- I agree it looks stupid; I think you missed my point: > "you already use Math... **instead of** `1...`".  Using a namespace like `String.reverse("string")` vs. the prototype chain `"string".reverse()` does, as you say, come down to preference.  Going back to my question -- why should you prefer one vs. the other? _(Again, when writing your own functions, not using native functionality)_

Comment: @drzaus You're correct that both reverse implementations are valid.  The Object oriented version is more succinct though, and has the advantage that if you had reverse methods for several different types, you could call obj.reverse without having to know which type you were using.  That doesn't make a whole lot of sense for reverse, but it can for other cases (toString comes to mind as a good example.)  In the end, you can write your code in whatever style you find readable and maintainable. But these patterns do have real advantages in readability and flexibility

Comment: @ben336 - which is why I'm now leaning towards it being the difference between OOP and FnP -- it depends on what you're in the middle of doing

Answer (score 1):

There are many cases where you may wish to use `this` instead of passing an extra parameter. Consider the following function for example:

```
Function.prototype.async = function () {
    setTimeout.bind(null, this, 0).apply(null, arguments);
};
```

This function allows us to defer a function call as follows:

```
alert.async("This will display later.");
alert("This will display first.");
```

You can see the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/AjwQu/

Instead of binding the function to `this` we could have passed it as a parameter instead:

```
function async(funct) {
    setTimeout.bind(null, funct, 0).apply(null, [].slice.call(arguments, 1));
}
```

We would use it like this now:

```
async(alert, "This will display later.");
alert("This will display first.");
```

The result is the same: http://jsfiddle.net/63dBF/

However to get the arguments we have to use `[].slice.call(arguments, 1)` instead. In the first example we could simply use `arguments` as the function was not a part of the argument list.

Everything has it's advantages and disadvantages. You just need to know what to use when. Hope this helps a bit.

**Bonus:** It's really easy to convert a function that uses `this` into a function that accepts an extra parameter and vice versa. First let's define a few utility functions:

```
var functProto = Function.prototype;

var bind = functProto.bind;

var bindable = bind.bind(bind);
var callable = bindable(functProto.call);
var appliable = bindable(functProto.apply);
```

The `bindable` function allows you to create a bindable version of an existing function which when called returns a new function bound to the given arguments.

The `callable` function allows you to create a callable version of an existing function which when called calls the existing function with the given arguments and `this` pointer.

The `appliable` function allows you to create an appliable version of an existing function which when called applies the given arguments and `this` pointer to the existing function.

Then given the function in the first example we can create the function in the second example as follows:

```
var async = callable(functProto.async);
```

See the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/3dSBS/

Similarly we can convert the function in the second example into the function in the first example as follows:

```
Function.prototype.async = function () {
    return async.apply(null, [this].concat([].slice.call(arguments)));
};
```

See the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/rJQyS/

As you can see it's much easier to write a function using `this` and then construct the function accepting the context as a parameter from it than the other way around.

Comment: What you demonstrate is mostly "syntatic sugar", i.e. it looks cooler to write one way vs. the other.  See http://jsfiddle.net/drzaus/63dBF/2/ -- I can use `asynca(fn, [args])` in the same manner, not needing to slice arguments, and it "works just as well" (better, actually, re: `console.log`).  My point was more towards is there some kind of performance benefit, since the maintainability of explicit vs. implicit context is debatable (think generating callback functions for jQuery events and tracing `this` around).

Comment: @drzaus - Oops, I know that your code was well intended but your function `asynca` does not work as expected. The problem is that you're calling `fn.apply(null, args)` before `setTimeout` is executed. Common mistake. It's supposed to be `setTimeout(function () { return fn.apply(null, args); }, 0)`. See [your code](http://jsfiddle.net/63dBF/3/) and [mine](http://jsfiddle.net/63dBF/4/). I don't see how your code works better wrt `console.log`. That being said there's no performance benefit of using `this` over an extra argument. It's just a matter of preference. Only 4 characters left to go. =-)

Comment: Good point, [fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/drzaus/63dBF/6/).  Re: `console.log` -- it actually doesn't work for either yours or mine, I guess `console.log` is just a weird function -- it throws "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation".  As we keep saying, maybe it's just preference.

Comment: Upvoting for useful discussion.

Comment: @drzaus - Which browser are you using? I'm using Opera 12.14 amd64 on Ubuntu 12.10 and it works perfectly for me. I don't know why it's not working for you but it's definitely not because of my `async` function. Try `console.log.bind(console).async("Something to print.")` instead.

Comment: Windows 7 Chrome whatever & IE 9 both fail on all accounts (both yours and mine) with `console.log`.  Binding it first as you suggest [does seem to fix the issue though](http://jsfiddle.net/drzaus/63dBF/9/), but that kinda brings me back to my point -- the use of `this` somewhere can make it more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

When you do object oriented programming your functions WILL depend on the context and it does not make sense do provide it as a parameter, as this would deafeat the purpose of object oriented programming.

It also makes sense to provide an implicit context for callbacks. You do not have to remember the correct order of the parameters if you only need the context. You would not have to use parameters at all in that case. So instead of

`function mayCallback(param1, param2, context)`

you could just write

`function myCallback()`

and use `this`, if you do not need param1 and param2.